Gradient Border In WinForms
I try to do a Gradient border color from White to Transparent.
Hi everyone!, I tried to do a gradient border in winforms from white color to transparent. I add a Panel in the form and set transparencykey and backcolor, but when modify OnPaint and add a lineargradient,in the transparency color see the backcolor. Any know how to do this?

Please edit your question to include the code you've written so that we can provide suggestions for fixing the problem.

You need to create custom panel inhericts from Panel. Use LinearGradientBrush to create the gradient.
GradientBorderPanel draws the gradient border from white color to transparent
